# Google Cardboard video gets paused automatically

Tags: applications, video-streaming, nexus-5x, google-cardboard

I just bought a new Google Cardboard and downloaded the official Google Cardboard app.

The problem is when I play videos in the Google Cardboard app they are pausing automatically, which is very frustrating.

I tried to play them without putting my phone in the cardboard, but the video still pauses.

I am using the Nexus 5X